# What is the difference between lead tetraacetate and sodium periodate as reagents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reagents

[image]I recently came across this question which has confused me about the  usage of $\ce{Pb(OAc)4}$ and $\ce{NaIO4}$ reagent.

Both the reagents have nearly the same cyclization mechanism, but the answer to this problem says that $\ce{Pb(OAc)4}$ should be used for the conversion instead of $\ce{NaIO4}$.

The first thing that I noticed was that, the compound is a trans-1,2-diol, so $\ce{NaIO4}$ might not be the appropriate reagent, but I could not understand how $\ce{Pb(OAc)4}$ is appropriate for this conversation .

Please suggest the essential difference between these reagents.

Comment: I am not sure but the book from which I studied the mechanism, it is written that the cyclic mechanism was proposed by Criegee. Perhaps after investigation that mechanism was discarded.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criegee_oxidation . It gives several mechanisms. The radical one is for beta-amino alcohols so maybe I was wrong.